# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: sql-server

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions out there seem to work. I did `logshipping` some 3 days ago in Microsoft SQL Server and it worked just fine on 4 databases all of which are located on the same Secondary server. Today 3 days after one of the databases keeps giving me the error `[298] SQLServer Error: 18456, Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [SQLSTATE 28000]` I do not understand why, the other 3 databases are still `logshipping` effortlessly. A solution I found online was to make the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`as the `DB owner` of the `failing database` sounds great but my databases are already in read only and that would be giving `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` too much control I do not see the reason why I should when it was able to log in just fine before. Has anyone been in such a situation and how did they resolve it?

Comment: You can't give `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` too much control -- the system account has administrative permissions and is already capable of doing anything, whether you mark it as an owner of something or not. So that, at least, is not a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As messed up as it might sound, it turns out log shipping was giving the wrong `error` not sure why but I fixed it by disabling the `Backup job` on the primary then disabling the `Copy and Restore Jobs` on secondary. Doing a full backup of the primary and restoring on secondary and a transaction log backup and restore on secondary then I enabled the jobs and viola log shipping started again.